# VM125:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token K in JSON at position 0

Tags: python, json, django, fetch, e-commerce

, I am working on this project which is of an e-commerce site using django. I created a view which will process the order of the user with respect to different scenarios if the user is authenticated or not.
Here is the code for the view.

```
transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
data = json.loads(request.body)

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
else:
    customer, order = guestOrder(request, data)

total = float(data['form']['total'])
order.transaction_id = transaction_id

if total == order.get_cart_total:
    order.complete = True
order.save()

if order.shipping == True:
    ShippingAddress.objects.create(
    customer=customer,
    order=order,
    address=data['shipping']['address'],
    city=data['shipping']['city'],
    state=data['shipping']['state'],
    zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
    )

return JsonResponse('Payment submitted..', safe=False)
```

Note: there are some functions which are in some other files if you want to check them do let me know.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUGeu.png)

in this image there are two bugs the first one is referring to process_order view (code above).

i am not able to resolve this issue.
and when i am trying to POST the data to the database

var url = "/process_order/"
fetch(url, {
method:'POST',
headers:{
'Content-Type':'applicaiton/json',
'Accept': 'application/json',
'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
},
body:JSON.stringify({'form':userFormData, 'shipping':shippingInfo}),

```
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
            alert('Transaction completed');
```

with this code also it in not sending data. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is not the whole story. The server also produces the 500 error, and this is most probably an HTML code with cannot be parsed by `response.json()` either. You should check the error in the python console and resolve it. You can also try looking at the browser dev tools to see the whole response produced by Django.

It's not clear why the error states `token 'K'`, probably it's from the not shown part of the code, but the issue lies, well, in the invalid JSON response produced by the server.

You cannot have a plain string as a top-level thing in the JSON specification. So instead of `JsonResponse('Payment submitted..')` you should use something like this:

```
JsonResponse({'detail': 'Payment submitted..'})
```

Same for all other instances of `JsonResponse` usage.